# Enabling foreign_keys=ON in sqlite3 through code

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sqlite

I have added the relationship in few table one-one, one-many...

I created database and tables programatically I want to enable foreign_keys for my tables,
for which I am firing `sqlite3_excec(db,PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON,0,0,&error)`

which is not working! it's creating text file instead of sqlite3.

please let me know if any solution to enable `PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;` in sqlite3

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for,but please check this link http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Answer (score 1):

write this code in method where you open the database

```
sqlite3_stmt *enableForeignKey;
NSString *strsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON"];

const char *sql=(char *)[strsql UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql,-1, &enableForeignKey, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR IN PRAGMA!");
}
```